# Grepping file paths in java

Tags: java, file, path, grep

I am currently working on Gitlet, which is a version control system modeled after Git. Currently, my commits are stored in folders each of which have their commit ID as the folder name. Each file needs to be "inherited" on to the next commit if it hasn't been changed, but I cannot copy the contents of the previous commit into the new commit in order to save space. I am achieving this inheritance by storing files (keys) and their paths (values) in a `HashMap`. Each commit has its own `HashMap` with its own inherited files. When the user adds a file, as of now, I just discovered that I am only taking into account the case where thes user is actually in the directory where the file is found. I am not taking into account whether the user is out of the directory that the file its in. This brings up a large issue, because the path that gets copied over to the hashmap is `<folder/folder2/file.txt = commits/3/folder/folder2/file.txt>`, when i actually just want `<file.txt = commits/3/file.txt>`

Is there an "easy" way I can grep this so that the only things that get copied over are the actual file names instead of folder/folder2?

I am currently copying files like such:

```
          try {
                String path = "./.gitlet/commits/" + commitID;
                for (String file : stagedQueue) {

                        File temp = new File(path + file);
                        Files.copy((new File(file).toPath()), 
                            (new File(path + "/" + file).toPath()));

                }


            } catch (IOException e) { //closes try and starts catch
                e.printStackTrace();
            } //closes catch
```

Where stagedQueue is a `HashSet<String>` containing the files that have been added by the user to be included in the next commit

Comment: You don't mean `grep`. That's not even close to what you want here. You mean you want the file portion of that path only, right? So treat the string as a path and get the file portion of it (java should have functions for that I would imagine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% what you are looking for, but if you want just the file name, there's this:

```
File().getName();
File().getPath();
```

Then you just have to play a few games to get the right output path.